# Push docker image to remote server

Tags: maven, docker, spring-boot

I am new to `docker` and have followed https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/, so far successfully.

`docker` is installed and running on a different server in my network.

How can I push and run the image directly to that `docker`-server with maven?

Comment: You want to ask you can't push image to your server or you can't use maven to control docker to push and run image?

Answer (score 0):

[docker-maven-plugin](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin) probably does what you want